# Encrypt an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to encrypt an NSString so that it isn't human-readable. The level of security doesnt manner (in other words, if somebody were to decrypt the text there wouldn't be any sensitive information for them to steal.

```
NSString *myTextToEncrypt = @"Hello World!";

[myTextToEncrypt encrypt];

// myTextToEncrypt is now something unreadable, like '2rwzdn1405'
```

Then I should be able to unencrypt this string

```
[myTextToEncrypt unencrypt]; // myTextToEncrypt should now be @"Hello World!" again
```

How do I do this? I've read some about CommonCrypto and AES Encryption but this all seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do (the encryption methods I've read are all for passwords or other sensitive pieces of data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to do this.

There are some implementations in Objective-C available (as [this one](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)).

Note that the content will be about 30% bigger after it's encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest one is use your own encryption, e.g.

**Utils.h**

```
@interface Utils : NSObject
+(NSString*)encyptString:(NSString*)str;
+(NSString*)decryptString:(NSString*)str;
@end
```

**Utils.m**

```
#import "Utils.h"

int offset = 15;
@implementation Utils
+(NSString*)encyptString:(NSString*)str
{
    NSMutableString *encrptedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        unichar character = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        character += offset;
        [encrptedString appendFormat:@"%C",character];
    }
    return encrptedString;
}

+(NSString*)decryptString:(NSString*)str
{
    NSMutableString *decrptedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        unichar character = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        character -= offset;
        [decrptedString appendFormat:@"%C",character];
    }
    return decrptedString;
}
@end
```

How to use it

```
NSString *str = @"hello world";
NSString *enr = [Utils encyptString:str];
NSLog(@"Encrypted Text=%@", enr);
NSLog(@"Decrypted Text=%@", [Utils decryptString:enr]);
```

Logs

```
2013-08-11 10:44:09.409 DeviceTest[445:c07] Encrypted Text=wt{{~/~{s
2013-08-11 10:44:09.412 DeviceTest[445:c07] Decrypted Text=hello world
```

Comment: This is not encryption, this is encoding, which is easier to penetrate.

Comment: @Jasconius How much easier is it to penetrate? I thinking of using encoding to 'encrypt' some text messages.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore The offset needs to have a limit? or can I pass the number I want no matter what the text is?